# Script Redirecting Even when valid

Tags: php

This is a little script that supposed to redirect if someone came from a different page, but it's does not work. 
It keeps redirecting to the form page.

Here's the code

```
<?php

define('FORM', 'form.html');
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

// this keeps redirecting even when I came by submiting the form to this page
if ( $referer != FORM ) {
   header('Location: ' .FORM);
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Testing 123</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
        $name  = $_GET['name'];
        $surname  = $_GET['surname'];
        echo 'hello'. $name. 'nice to see you here mr' .$surname;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'HTTP_REFERER' --> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; exit;`

Comment: @yi_h Thanks but your tip doesn't make much sense

Comment: it does. it's called tracing/debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose what is causing you trouble, is that you don't exit the script after calling header():

```
header('Location: ' . FORM);
exit;
```

Anyway you should consider checking for the required parameters, instead of relying on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, as sending the referrer-info may be disabled in the user's browser.

```
isset($_GET['name']) : $name = $_GET['name'] ? $name = null;
isset($_GET['surname']) : $surname = $_GET['surname'] ? $surname = null;

if (empty($name) || empty($surname)) {
    header('Location: ' . FORM);
    exit;
}
```

Additionally you should escape `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['surname']` before outputting it!

Answer (score 1):

You could test if the user came from the "form page" by checking if a certain $_POST variable has been sent. For example you could try something like

```
if(isset($_POST['somehiddenvalue']) && $_POST['somehiddenvalue'] == $hiddenVal) {
   // ok.
} else {
   // redirect
}
```

The user will still be able to manipulate the Post variables, keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I just wanted to make sure that the form was in fact submitted from my website - and not someone trying to make up a page and try to post to my script.

Comment: using HTTP_REFERER for validation is not the best option. This answer provides some fair behavior. For some good security, you may use something like: $someHiddenValue = sha1('securityToken'); use the hidden value in the form, then in your script: if(isset($_POST['somehiddenvalue']) && $_POST['somehiddenvalue'] === sha1('securityToken')) { // form was submitted }